# Реализовать поиск на React с выводом результатов в отдельной странице

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, redux, поиск

Как можно реализовать поиск на React, чтобы после нажатия на поиск результаты выводились на отдельной странице, предназначенной для вывода результатов поиска.

Как я понимаю можно использовать API контекста или Redux, чтобы передавать данные результата поиска между страницами. То есть при нажатии на поиск на какой-нибудь странице приложения вызывается функция, которая делает запрос на сервер, получает ответ и обновляет состояние контекста или Redux'а. После этого происходит переход на страницу с выводами результатов поиска и там уже рендерится обновленное состояние результатов.

Является ли это решение наиболее приемлемым, адекватным? Или есть другие способы реализации поиска? Возможен ли сначала переход на страницу с результатами и затем запрос данных с сервера?

Comment: Вы можете использовать `useNavigate` и передать `state` или же нормальным способом - `get` параметром или `params` с `useParams()`

Comment: Спасибо! Но не очень понял про `state`. Не могли бы уточнить?

Comment: Прочитайте про второй параметр `options` [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)

Comment: Чтобы потом получить этот `state` воспользуйтесь `useLocation`

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

В `Redux`-е хранил бы состояние, которое будет отвечать за данные введённые в поиске. После нажатия на "Поиск", перенаправил бы на нужную страницу, где в самом начале в первую очередь берутся данные для поиска из `Redux`-а, а потом делается запрос на сервер, с данными поиска. Пока ответа нет, показываем
лоадер, а после загрузки данных убираем лоадер и показываем то что нам надо

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Все-таки Redux используется для больших приложений, а у меня это пока небольшой проект. Так что хотел бы уточнить:  можно ли сделать похожим образом, только передача введенных данных поиска между страницами выполнялась бы не с помощью Redux, а с помощью параметров URL? Если можно, то:

1. Не будет тогда каких-нибудь подвохов?
2. Какой путь указывать такой странице в react-router-dom? (`/search/:query`?)
3. Переход на страницу выполнять с помощью `<form>` или `useNavigate()`?

Comment: Подвохов нет. Всё зависит от того, где-то ещё будут нужны эти параметры или нет? Если они нужны только на самой странице, то можно передать с помощью [useNavigate().options.state](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate). Можно передать с помощью `query` параметров и потом по одному их доставать с помощью [useParams()](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params), в таком случае, парамтеры надо будет указывать в роутере с помощью синтаксиса `/search/:query/:params`

Comment: @ameikz Если параметров очень много, то можно не указывать ничего в роутере с помощью `/:query/:params`, а просто воспользоваться [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) и достать сразу все парамтеры